# Flutter won't build MacOS app with Associated Domains entitlement

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm using the combination of the uni_links and uni_links_macos plugins.  Everything works fine with a build for iOS.  When I add an associated domain to DebugProfile.entitlements (either in VSCode or using Xcode), flutter build fails with:

```
error: Provisioning profile "Mac Team Provisioning Profile: com.example.app" doesn't include the currently selected device "MacBook Pro M1" (identifier XXX). (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
```

However, the app builds and runs fine from Xcode, so all the signing stuff is correct.

Flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel dev, 2.1.0-10.0.pre, on macOS 11.2.2 20D80 darwin-arm, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.54.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
```

Is this a flutter build bug which should be reported somewhere?

Thanks.

Comment: did you ever find a solution?  I saw the [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/77941) you made was triaged and given P4 in May but is still open. I'm now facing the same problem and surprised to not see any other issues or posts. Did you get anywhere?  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, no. I didn’t get anywhere with this.

Comment: I eventually got pas the issue I was seeing - I think it's the same as you describe - on an M1 Mac the device that XCode had automatically registered had the Provisioning UUID rather than the Hardware UUID.  However I did not have the same issue you did where the Developer console gave an error that the Hardware UUID is not valid. I was able to register a new device with the Hardware UUID and then "flutter run" worked.  Very happy to try and trouble shoot if you are still interested in this. Thanks for putting in the work to make the issue.

Comment: Oh I just noticed on your [screenshot](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/31779055/111169849-f517c200-8568-11eb-86c9-5fa634334a77.png) that the Platform is set to "iOS, tvOS, watchOS" rather than "MacOS" - could that have been the problem do you think?